# Is there any way to reset android setup wizard without factory reset and show setup wizard after the reboot device

Tags: android, android-tv, adb, setup-wizard

I am designing my own launcher for Android TV and Android devices and after the install my Android TV launcher; I need to reset the Android TV setup wizard without root device or Android TV.

I tried with manually clear data of the setup wizard from the device setting; System Installed applications and some ADB shell commands.